# Clone on sale badge onto product description single page but only for products on sale

Tags: php, jquery, css, wordpress, woocommerce

I am trying to have my `.onsale` badge to show on the product page (not the shop page) and for it to only show for products that are on sale. The reason that I am trying to clone the `.onsale` badge is so that I am able to apply different CSS to both of them, one for the shop page, and one for the product page.

**Working Code To Clone `.onsale`:**

```
jQuery( function($) {
$(".onsale").clone().appendTo(".entry-wrap").addClass("onsale2");
});
```

**My Attempt to apply `.onsale2` only to products that are on sale:**

```js
jQuery( function($) {
    if( $product->is_on_sale() ) {
        return $(".onsale").clone().appendTo(".entry-wrap").addClass("onsale2");
    }
});
```

How can I make it work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try that in wp_footer hook this way:

```
add_action( 'wp_footer', 'add_on_sale_badge' );
function add_on_sale_badge(){
    global $product;
    // Only on single product pages and on sale products
    if ( is_product() && $product->is_on_sale() ):
    ?>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery(function($){
        $(".onsale").clone().appendTo(".entry-wrap").addClass("onsale2");
    });
    </script>
    <?php
    endif;
}
```

Code goes in function.php file of your active child theme (or active theme). It should works.

Comment: Okay thank you, should I remove my current JQuery code an put this new one you have given me in `function.php` ?

Comment: @RedecIndustrial *"Code goes in function.php file of your active child theme"* … Try it and let me know.